# Java NIO Http client requests with thread pools

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, nio, threadpoolexecutor

Thread Pool Executor uses number of threads for Future Task.
It assigns at least one thread until run() or call() returns.

So, I am confused on how to use Thread Pool for JAVA NIO HTTP requests.

1) Which thread will run the event loop

2) As threads won't block on IO, They will exit the run/call method.
   Then who takes care of invoking their handlers.

My Question is how to use Java NIO based HTTP POST client requests with thread pools ( Because of the High number of HTTP requests that we need to make), Or with Java NIO it is really not needed to run them on multiple threads, as the thread will never sleeps ( It always executes as there is nothing to block)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this is the philosophy. Multithreading can be used in 2 flavours (may be more, but it is not significant in this case). Traditional multithreading uses threads and blocking I/O. Task-grained multithreading (please suggest better term) is built upon traditional one and exploits following restrictions:

- task of type `Runnable` is a unit of work;
- task may not block;
- if a task wants to wait for a long event (e.g. finish of I/O or time interval) it prepares another task and arranges it to run after the event, and exits (returns from `Runnable.run()`).

Tasks are submitted for execution to a thread pool.

Asynchronous I/O perfectly fits in task-oriented model. Futures are glue between thread-oriented and task-oriented programming styles. They can be used to pass information from tasks to threads, but not in opposite direction, because tasks may not block. So you need not to use Futures at all when designing fully asynchronous server.

NIO1 requires a selector thread. Create and run it separately of the thread pool. NIO2 (java7) does not require selector thread (it maintains it in the background so that user does not to bother).

It is easy to find examples of NIO servers. [df4j](https://github.com/rfqu/df4j) has examples of echo-servers (but not http servers) for both NIO1 and NIO2.

Comment: I am not able to find thread pool usage at https://github.com/rfqu/df4j/tree/master/df4j-nio2/src

It really helps if you can give some concrete examples too.

Comment: df4j-nio2 is not a separate project. Look at df4j-nio, which is a base, and  df4j-nio2 or  df4j-nio1 should be added in classpath depending on what implementation you want to use. Threadpool is not used directly in df4j, it is created automatically when needed and is kept as a thread-local variable. It can be accessed via com.github.rfqu.df4j.core.DFContext.getCurrentExecutorService(). Read Readme.md at https://github.com/rfqu/df4j

Comment: Thanks :)
If there are no more responses, this can be marked as answer.